# Спорити чи битись об заклад?

Tags: переклад, існування-слова

Найчастіше чую "битись об заклад". Але кілька разів чула слова "спорити", "спір", "спор". Який варіант є правильним?

У тлумачному словнику знайшла:

СПІР 1, спору, чол.

1. Словесне змагання; обговорення чого-небудь двома або кількома особами, в якому кожна з сторін обстоює свою думку, свою правоту. 
   //  Полеміка (звичайно в пресі) з рівних питань науки, літератури, політики і т. ін.
   //  Серйозна суперечка; сварка. 
   //  перен. Суперечність, зіткнення.
2. перев. мн. Взаємні домагання щодо володіння чим-небудь, посідання чогось і т. ін., вирішувані перев. судом.

СПОРИТИ, рю, риш, недок.

1. розм. Те саме, що сперечатися.
2. перен. Змагатися, не поступатися у чому-небудь.

Вислів "битися об заклад" знайшла лише у фразеологічному словнику:

Об заклад битися (побитися) у ролі прис. — сперечатися з кимсь, бувши цілком переконаним у чому-небудь.

Answer (score 2):

Правильними є обидва варіанти. Відмінність лише у тому, що

> **Спорити** - розмовне від літературного [сперечатися](http://sum.in.ua/s/sperechatysja).

Так пише [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/sporyty).

У тому ж таки [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaklad) знаходжу і таку статтю:

> **Битися (побитися) об (у) заклад; Іти (піти) в заклад** — сперечатися на гроші, яку-небудь річ і т. ін.

Оскільки СУМ-11 - це академічне видання, йому слід довіряти.

Отже, як я вище писала, вживання обидвох варіантів є правильними, відмінність лише у тому, що "**спорити**" - розмовне, а "**битись об заклад**" - сталий вислів.